# "New answers to old questions" no longer shows deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, old-questions, new-answers

**For Bounty:** Either a satisfactory explanation for why it's better not to see deleted items *or* a plan for it to be returned.

---

Before the "Links" moderator tools page got reworked a few weeks ago, the "New Answers to Old Questions" page used to show **deleted** answers.  It now appears to filter out those answers.

This prevents me from knowing when I've "caught up". (when, 5 pages in, I see a flurry of deleted answers, I consider it safe to assume that other people have spent some time on these older answers.)  Being unable to do this now somehow disincentivizes me from perusing the list.  I would greatly prefer that deleted answers still show up in the list of answers.

If there is a good reason for this change, may I inquire what that reason was?

Comment: can anyone explain what the question is?

Comment: @Damodar, the question?  I want to know why deleted answers were removed from the *New Answers to Old Questions* queue.  And preferably, I'd like them returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If there is a good reason for this change, may I inquire what that reason was?

There wasn't a great reason either way, my thinking was you *wouldn't* want to see content that had already been dealt with when refactoring how this page worked (for performance).

But...you raise a good point on how seeing deleted answers is helpful, so in the next build they will return to this view.

Comment: Awesome, you've made my day. :)

Comment: not to look a gift-horse in the mouth, but the page now runs much slower (taking about 20-30 seconds to load).  Sometimes I'm getting the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" message too.  Not sure if this feature is deployed yet, but figured I'd mention the slowness.  (And hopefully a solution exists that is both fast and includes the deleted answers. :)  )

Comment: @Kirk - yup, I saw an error in the logs earlier, we'll be capping it to only look back 30 days in the next build which will speed things up, since it's bypassing the main index it was using at the moment.

Comment: Sweet, sounds good.